# How to use google routing OR-tools in php currently its using python

Tags: python, php, or-tools

Can anyone have idea or research how to use this (https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing) google route optimization code in PHP, as currently its using python or other language. If not then how can I connect this python code to my existing laravel code ?

Thanks